# error when linking a budget alert to pubsub on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a budget alert on GCP that creates a pub/sub message following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets-programmatic-notifications). I have tried this both using the cloud console and terraform to no availl

Using cloud console and setting up the pub/sub I get the following error:

```
The attempted action failed. Please try again.
```

When trying to do the same thing using terraform with the following:

```
resource "google_billing_budget" "budget" {
  display_name    = "test-budget"
  billing_account = "xxxx"
  budget_filter {
    projects               = ["projects/xxx"]
    credit_types_treatment = "INCLUDE_SPECIFIED_CREDITS"
    credit_types = [
      "SUSTAINED_USAGE_DISCOUNT",
      "DISCOUNT",
      "COMMITTED_USAGE_DISCOUNT",
      "COMMITTED_USAGE_DISCOUNT_DOLLAR_BASE",
      "SUBSCRIPTION_BENEFIT",
    ]
  }
  amount {
    specified_amount {
      currency_code = "EUR"
      units         = 10
    }
  }

  all_updates_rule {
    pubsub_topic                   = "projects/xxx/topics/budget_alerts"
  }

  threshold_rules {
    threshold_percent = 1.1
    spend_basis       = "FORECASTED_SPEND"
  }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error 400: Precondition check failed.googleapi: Error 400: Precondition check failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was the `Domain restricted sharing` on the organisation that was blocking the association of the alert with the pubsub topic. As explained in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets-programmatic-notifications#permissions_related_to_a_domain_restriction_constraint) you can remove the policy when linking the alert with the topic.